# Is it possible to open Textwindow and Graphicwindow at once?

Tags: smallbasic

I'm Korean Highschool student. I made a game about the rules of Korean spelling. The program that I want is.. [ If you choose the correct answer, the graphic window will show the next question and the text window will say " Great job. " ] Is it impossible?

I want to add my codes. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add codes.

Comment: Controls.ButtonClicked= whichButton

Sub whichButton
  clickedButton = Controls.LastClickedButton
  If clickedButton = butQuit Then
    Program.End()
  ElseIf clickedButton = butPlayGame then
    TextWindow.WriteLine("당신은 한국인이 아니군요.")
  ElseIf clickedButton = butMenu then
    createGameWindow1()
  ElseIf clickedButton = butStartGame then
    createGameWindow()
  ElseIF clickedButton = butPlayGame1 then
    TextWindow.WriteLine("한국어 공부에 분발하세요.")
  ElseIf clickedButton = butMenu1 then
     TextWindow.WriteLine("당신은 진정한 한국인입니다.")
  EndIf
EndSub

Comment: Sub setup
gww = 1000
gwh = 800
GraphicsWindow.Width = gww
GraphicsWindow.Height = gwh
EndSub

Sub createMainMenu
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "Blue"
GraphicsWindow.FontSize = 45
GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(350,100,300,"한글 맞춤법 문제")
butStartGame = Controls.AddButton("문제풀기", 400,300)
butQuit = Controls.AddButton("그만두기", 400, 500)
EndSub

Comment: Sub createGameWindow
GraphicsWindow.Clear()
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = " Blue "
GraphicsWindow.FontSize = 45
GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(350,100,300,"문제1")
butPlayGame = Controls.AddButton("넌 나에게 뒤치닥거리일 뿐이야.",400,300)
butMenu = Controls.AddButton("넌 나에게 뒤치닥꺼리일 뿐이야.", 400, 500)
EndSub

Comment: Sub createGameWindow1
  GraphicsWindow.Clear()
  GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor= " Green "
  GraphicsWindow.FontSize = 45
  GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(350,100,300,"문제2")
  butPlayGame1 = Controls.AddButton("시답잖은 말은 필요없어요.",400,300)
  butMenu1 = Controls.AddButton("시덥잖은 말은 필요없어요.",400,500)
EndSub

setup()
createMainMenu()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Just use TextWindow.WriteLine to show the Textwindow whenever.

```
showButton = Controls.AddButton("Show", 20, 20)
Controls.ButtonClicked = onButtonClicked

Sub onButtonClicked
  if Controls.LastClickedButton = showButton Then
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Button Clicked!")
    Shapes.Move(Shapes.AddText("Button Clicked!"), 20,50)
  EndIf
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I like coding in small basic and it is possible to show the text window and graphics window at the same time. You can use the following code to do this:

```
GraphicsWindow.Show()
TextWindow.Show()
```